# Convert integer into date and time in R?

Tags: r, date, time, integer

I got this dataset for cryptocurrencies with price and volume as follows:

```
> head(data)
          V1   
1 1672531202 
2 1672531203 
3 1672531330 
4 1672531438 
5 1672531443 
6 1672531466
```

The first column V1 is stored as 'integer' and it consists of date and time. How can I convert that column V1 into date and time column separately. Actually, I am not sure which date/time format is stored there since it is original data.

Comment: `df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$V1, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")` and second part: `df$Date <- as.Date(df$datetime)
df$Time <- format(df$datetime, "%T")` output: `V1            datetime     Time       Date
1 1672531202 2023-01-01 00:00:02 00:00:02 2023-01-01
2 1672531203 2023-01-01 00:00:03 00:00:03 2023-01-01
3 1672531330 2023-01-01 00:02:10 00:02:10 2023-01-01
4 1672531438 2023-01-01 00:03:58 00:03:58 2023-01-01
5 1672531443 2023-01-01 00:04:03 00:04:03 2023-01-01
6 1672531466 2023-01-01 00:04:26 00:04:26 2023-01-01`

Comment: If you don't know the format you can only guess. `as.POSIXct(1672531202, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")`
gives `"2023-01-01 00:00:02 UTC"` which might be a reasonable first data point for your dateset.